# How to create a BitLocker partition on Linux

Tags: bitlocker

I would like to create a BitLocker partition on my USB SSD. I have created a partition using fdisk. **I do not know which partition type to assign.** I assume I have to mount the partition using dislocker then format the created device.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use it but don't see any other solutions on linux:
[Hasleo BitLocker Anywhere For Linux](https://www.easyuefi.com/bitlocker-for-linux/bitlocker-for-linux.html)

Write answer if You try it ;)

If You looking for cross platform encryption for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows I can recommend to You [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It might be useful for someone. However, I am looking for a FOSS.